# Disable ambient noise reduction in macOS Catalina

Tags: terminal, audio, catalina, microphone

I think the ambient noise reduction is enabled by default in macOS Catalina, resulting in very poor audio quality using Rode plug-play microphone!

Is there any terminal command to disable ambient noise reduction in macOS Catalina?
[image]

As you can see the option made invisible in audio input settings since Catalina. Very unexpected form Apple!

## Solution

Re-installed macOS Mojave (I decided not to update to macOS Catalina at any cost)! Here is the screenshot from macOS Mojave with ambient noise reduction option.

[image]

Comment: I have happily downgraded to macOS mojave and decided not to update the OS.

Comment: Is there any way to disable this at least from the terminal?? My mic sounds like crap now and it's totally useless for recording instruments...

Comment: @ÓscarGómezAlcañiz Re-install macOS mojave

Comment: too late... it's also my work computer now that we are forced to telework due to COVID-19 

Comment: experiencing some problems here with music sound quality through FaceTime calls with piano teacher, believe it could be adjusted with a checkbox for ambient noise reduction which as above user mentioned, does not exist in Catalina!

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that the "Ambient Noise Reduction" feature only works with the internal microphone. Thus when you plug-in a Røde USB microphone, ambient noise reduction is not applied to that input. Therefore I suggest looking at other possible causes of bad audio quality or latency.

The lack of the checkbox for the internal microphone on Catalina is, as I understand it, a bug. Hopefully Apple will restore it in a point update.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a Terminal command that enables/disables ambient noise reduction. You might however want to check if the plists in the `/Library/Preferences/Audio/` folder contains a setting related to ambient noise reduction on your system.

However Apple's [documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2567/mac) seem to indicate that you can disable ambient noise reduction by setting up a 4-channel built-in microphone format with the Audio MIDI Setup program.