# How to disable the now default "ambient noise reduction" in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, catalina, audio, microphone

In macOS Catalina, ambient noise reduction is applied by default to audio of an external source coming in through the headphone jack. This is not always desired, e.g. when recording musical instruments. In previous versions of macOS, noise reduction could be disabled via System Preferences. However, this option is not present in Catalina. [This thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383465/disable-ambient-noise-reduction-in-macos-catalina) proposes downgrading to Mojave as a solution to the problem (which it is), though this is not desirable for me as I need Catalina for other reasons.

As mentioned in the thread, Apple's [audio documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2567/mac) specifies that ambient noise reduction is disabled if a 4-channel built-in microphone format is selected in Audio MIDI Setup. Unfortunately, my external audio source only supports 2 channels, so this option is unavailable in Audio MIDI Setup.

My guess is that the solution is any of the following:

1. Some terminal command to disable ambient noise reduction entirely.
2. Modifying some plist, e.g. in `/Library/Preferences/Audio/`.

However, I have not yet managed to find a solution, and would greatly appreciate it if anyone could think along. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps using a USB mic, or a mic <> USB audio interface would bypass the ambient noise reduction. Blue Snowball mics connect directly to USB 2.x ports. [Behringer](https://www.amazon.com/Behringer-U-Control-UCA222-Ultra-Low-Interface/dp/B0023BYDHK) makes some excellent interfaces.

Comment: Definitely true, a Focusrite 4i4 is already present. Though I have a tiny 6.35 mm to 3.5 mm audio interface which I can bring along my MacBook very easily wherever I go for a quick recording session on the fly. Nothing fancy, but it does the job! Except for the noise reduction... ;-)

Comment: Does the following _command_ in **Terminal** return anything? `defaults read -g | grep -E '[A-F0-9]{8}_'`

Comment: The reason I ask, is on a system running **10.13** if I toggle the checkbox for **Use ambient noise reduction** the **~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist** file sets `1`/`0` _checked_/_unchecked_ on a _key_ that's formatted as `[A-F0-9]{8}_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{8}_[A-F0-9]{8}_[A-F0-9]{8}`, e.g. `646F6E7A_00000000_00000001_6E7A6361_696D6963` for the **Internal Microphone Built-in**. Testing with another external microphone the _value_ of the last group of 8 _characters_ changed in the **plist** _file_. Checking the **Internal Microphone** on two different **Macs** the _keys_ were identical.

Comment: So, if you toggled the setting previously before upgrading to **10.15** maybe the _key_ exists and you can use e.g. `defaults write -g "646F6E7A_00000000_00000001_6E7A6361_696D6963" -int 0` to set it as _unchecked_. While I didn't need to use `killall cfprefsd` directly after the previous _command_ under **10.13**, you might need to under **10.15**. If the _key_ isn't there, you would have to boot the **Mac** from e.g. a **USB** drive running a earlier **OS** to get the _key_. This approach may not work in **10.15** but it's the only solution I can think of that might work. Good Luck!

Comment: This looks very promising! Well explained and thanks for the effort. I will see if it works this evening when I have time.

NB: the output of the first command is `"646F6E7A_00000000_00000001_6E7A6361_656D6963" = 1;` and `"646F6E7A_00000000_00000001_6E7A6361_696D6963" = 1;`

Comment: Hopefully setting both of those _keys_ to `0` will act as if the box was unchecked. Let me know if it works and I'll post it as an answer, thanks.

Comment: I have just tried it, and unfortunately it does not seem to work. I can confirm that the value in the .plist has changed to 0, though the ambient noise reduction is still present. Which is a pity as it seemed like a really good suggestion. Might there be any other process I have to terminate / restart, before the change has any impact?

Comment: Was **System Preferences**  closed and did you use `killall cfprefsd` directly after the `defaults` _command_? If yes and it didn't work then **macOS Catalina** is ignoring that setting, which I have seen similar in other upgrade scenarios. So what I presented was the only thing I could think of. Maybe someone else will come along with a definitive answer.

Comment: I tried it once more following you by the word, though Catalina seems to ignore this setting. Really appreciate the effort anyway! Indeed, maybe someone else will come along.

Comment: Another thought; might we be able to fake the amount of input channels? Currently there are two, though Apple's docs (see link in post) state that ANR is disabled for inputs with 4 channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the best solution... is a little patience! I have recently updated to MacOS Big Sur (11.0.1), and the checkbox to disable ambient noise reduction is available again in the sound input settings.

However, there is a caveat: the toggle is available only to a subset of devices. Please note the following, stated on Apple's website:

> *Capture less background noise when using your computer’s built-in
> microphone: Select “Use ambient noise reduction”.* This option does not
> appear if a 4-channel built-in microphone format is selected in Audio
> MIDI Setup or on Mac models with an Apple T2 chip.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/mac-help/mchlp2567/mac

[image: Big Sur Rules]